# Custom conda sub channel

Tags: anaconda, conda, artifactory

Trying to setup remote repository for https://anaconda.org/MOSEK/mosek but that URL is not playing nice and unable to find what the conda manager would redirect to when connecting to sub channels by default.

What's the remote URL to add for these custom / sub channels from Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

To proxy Anaconda Cloud (anaconda.org) please use https://conda.anaconda.org as the remote repository URL.

[image]

Make sure you are [adding it as channel](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Conda+Repositories#CondaRepositories-ResolvingCondaPackages) to `.condarc` for example:

```
channels:
  - http://admin:password@localhost:8081/artifactory/api/conda/anaconda.org
```

Or better aggregating all the remote Conda repositories under a single [virtual Conda repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Conda+Repositories#CondaRepositories-VirtualRepositories) and adding it as your default channel.

Answer (score 0):

Conda will resolve Anaconda user channels by name. That is, if you just do

```
conda config --add channels MOSEK
```

it will add your channel to those that are searched (i.e., to `.condarc`). For example, you can now simply run

```
conda install mosek
```

If you set this up, and then check `conda info`, you will see the associated URLs:

```
https://conda.anaconda.org/MOSEK/osx-64
https://conda.anaconda.org/MOSEK/noarch
```

The subdirectories here depend on the platform of your machine.

---

If you don't want to add the channel to your full configuration, but just install specific packages, you would run

```
conda install MOSEK::mosek
```

or

```
conda install -c MOSEK mosek
```